# Associations: multiple hasMany and belongsTo implementation

Tags: node.js, express

so I have three models:

*Book*, *Review* and *User*. I want the associations to be such that:

*User* has many *Review*

*Book* has many *Review*

doing it like:

```
Book.hasMany(Review);
Review.belongsTo(Book);

User.hasMany(Review);
Review.belongsTo(User);
```

does not work, it gives this error:
*Naming collision between attribute 'user' and association 'user' on model review. To remedy this, change either foreignKey or as in your association definition*

what can I do or where can I read about this? Thank you further!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should have an instance of you model and then use something like this code :

```
  Review.associate = (models) => {
    models.Review.belongsTo(models.Book, {
      foreignKey: 'bookId',
      targetKey: 'id'
    })
  }
```

And you can add how many association you want with something like this code

Answer (score 0):

You can  simply specify an alias for the foreign key of the user in the model review as follows :

```
Review.belongsTo(User, {foreignKey: 'owner_user_id'});
```

This is all mentioned in sequelize documentation page on associations : 
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/associations.html